# Word to describe the quality of being optional or mandatory

Tags: single-word-requests, parts-of-speech

Something like 'Optionality' or 'Ordinality'? (It's similar in kind to the words "Arity" and "Cardinality")

Example: "Fred listed the XXXity of each parameter, noting whether it was optional or mandatory"

Follow-up question:
What part of speech is this?

Comment: *Optionality* is obviously a noun (you are even using it with a definite article in your example) and is included as such in several dictionaries (Wiktionary, Merriam-Webster, Collins). And in fact some dictionaries have a dedicated entry for the suffix [*-ity*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ity).

Comment: I see - as in "noun referring to a state or quality"... so there isn't a specific word for this?

Comment: How about 'Necessity'? Does a thesaurus help?

Comment: Are looking for a part of speech more refined than 'noun'? You're looking for an abstract concept but there's nothing grammatically special about that.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/341273/183927

Answer (score 19):

There are a few recently contrived words that try to do this; *optionality* is indeed used from time to time, and I've seen things like *mandatoriness* too. But actually there are some more established words that do the same job.

Of course, optional-ness is actually binary - something is either optional or mandatory. Therefore the quality of optionality/optional-ness is actually the same as the quality of mandatory-ness or compulsory-ness, just with the polarity reversed.

All of which is a fairly long winded way for me to get around to saying this:

I think the word you're looking for is the noun, *[necessity](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=necessity&tbs=dfn:1)*.

Comment: The problem with 'necessity' is that it doesn't play well in if-statements i.e. `if (foo.necessity) doSmth()` doesn't look good to me.

Comment: @Roman Necessity is the quality (parameter/variable), not the state/value - for that you might use "necessary", "mandatory" or an antonym such as "optional". Something like `if (foo.necessity == 'mandatory') doSmth(); elseif (foo.necessity == 'optional') doSmthElse(); else doNecNotSet();` is what we're talking about here. Necessity doesn't hold true/false values, it holds values like "necessary", "mandatory", "optional" etc.

But treating English like a programming language isn't always the best way to go, because it isn't one.

Comment: I arrived here as I wanted to check if **"requirement"** would be the right fit. As it's a synonym of *"necessity"* (with high relevance according to [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/necessity?s=t)), I think it works too. *"Requirement"* sounds more formal that *"Necessity"* and I'm using it as a header for a column where the values are *"Mandatory"* or *"Optional"*.

Comment: On second thought, ***condition*** (where it means a state that must be fulfilled) can also be a good alternative (though not a synonym of *necessity* or *requirement*). For example, "What is the condition to be met, with regards to this item?" "The item is mandatory" or "The item is optional".

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/341273/183927):

> requisiteness
>
> NOUN
>
> The fact of being requisite; necessity, need.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that **Ordinality** is used in this sense (even though it has a more normal meaning of 'ordering'). Maybe this is verging on jargon.

For example:
    "Ordinality is a property that indicates whether an entity instance is mandatory"

(from: '[Oracle SQL and Pl/SQL Handbook: A Guide for Data Administrators, Developers](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Qd5i7I2yGuoC&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=ordinality&source=bl&ots=tVkJwch30K&sig=c8XEM4og66aiidX0GFCD-hOtXr4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Z1BdUcCII4WMO9bYgOAO&ved=0CGQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=ordinality&f=false)')

Comment: Naming of database properties isn't always a guide to good English usage.

Comment: Agreed, but in this case the context happened to be appropriate :)

Comment: This isnt quite right tho - ordinality expresses a reference to an index of an item in a list of things

Answer (score 0):

Mandatory doesn't really mean that something is not optional. This would explain why there isn't really a word to answer your question. The question has a wrong defintion of mandatory. If it was optional or required then you could say electivity.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).