# The extent to which something is required or mandatory

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't think of how to express this. Mandatoriness is closest I can come up with but I don't think it's a word.

Comment: How are you planning on using this word? Can you add a sentence example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word to describe the quality of being optional or mandatory](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110394/word-to-describe-the-quality-of-being-optional-or-mandatory)

Comment: @Hot Licks' linked question had *necessity* as its top answer, which I like. But I'd actually recommend rewording the sentence: "is this feature required?" or "how mandatory is this feature?" sound more natural than "what is the [necessity] of this feature?"

Comment: How necessary is this feature?

Comment: Include in your question the research you’ve done. Questions which lack results of research may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think *mandatoriness* is necessarily wrong. It seems logical to me.

*[Requisiteness](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/requisiteness)* however might be a more elegant word.

> **requisiteness**
>
> NOUN
>
> The fact of being requisite; necessity, need.
>
> [[oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/requisiteness)]

Comment: REQUITY would be even more elegant ;)

But it's not a word (yet)

Answer (score 3):

The form I would use is ["requisite."](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=requisite)

It is mainly used in a past participle/adjectival form, but can be a noun.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I have actually changed the title of the question to be "the extent to which something is required". How I had it before "the quality of being required" is more of a binary thing, for which your answer would have been correct. Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Required or mandatory are binary, either an object is required or not, it cannot be partially required otherwise required is the wrong word.

As a result, something that was *very required* would be defined as *useful* or *important*.

Therefore I think ***usefulness*** or ***importance*** would work, depending on the context.

> Usefulness: being of use or service; serving some purpose; advantageous, helpful, or of good effect<sup>[1](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/usefulness?s=t)</sup>
>
> Importance: he quality or state of being important; consequence; significance.<sup>[2](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/importance?s=t)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *[essentiality](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/essentiality)* (also *essentialness*)

> the quality or state of being essential: *the essentiality of freedom and justice* — P. G. Hoffman

*Merriam-Webster*

Answer (score 1):

[Cruciality](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cruciality).

Crucial means:

> Extremely important or necessary.

Example:

> One of the things that might make me work hard and efficiently on a project is the degree of *cruciality* of completing it on time.